# What should be done to a new young cat?

Tags: cats, junior-pets

I will get a cat (2-3 months) in about a month. I understand that I should vaccinate her soon, besides, is there anything else?

I will be getting that cat from a private individual and she will stay outside (as it currently is living). I have no other cats.

Answer (score 1):

She will require 3 rounds of vaccinations before she's 6 months old

You should find out which brand of food it currently eats. If it is not your preferred brand you will still need to buy some. Suddenly changing brands, most of the time, will upset their gut. You can slowly transition: 1/4 new food 1st day, half and half day 2, three quarters new food day 3.

It is recommended that you keep a cat/kitten inside for the first week. 
You (or another pet) will need to replace it's littermates and play with it. Safe homemade toys are fine you don't have to buy them. Piece of string, *empty* thread spool, screwed up piece of paper or peg are all fun toys.

Depending on your vet you can get your kitten spayed or neutered at 1 or 2 kilograms, 2kg is the norm

Comment: Three? I called a vet and she said cats need 2 rounds one after another (after 1 month)

Comment: It might be a difference between our countries- we have three rounds.

Answer (score 1):

You should take her to the vet when you get her. What we needed to do in that situation was:

- vaccinations
- check and (if necessary) treat her for fleas
- check and (if necessary) treat her for worms and other parasites

I would also propose to get another kitten. Now it should be easy for them to get used to each other. A kitten is very playful and needs a playmate. We had a single grown cat at first and thought it would be fine. That cat was looking like a loner, but after a few months, he became crazy.  After getting another cat he really calmed down. With a kitten that's even more important, I think.

Comment: I called a vet and she said that cats that stay outside need to do take a medicine like 3-4 times a year to avoid parasites AND worms. What's your experience?

Comment: That's possible. Ours live inside only. They get a worm treatment once a year. But for outside cats it has to be more often